# Convert Float32Array to base64 in javascript

Tags: javascript, base64

There are many Q&A's about converting blobs or `Uint8Array` to base64. But I have been unable to find how to convert from 32-bit arrays to base64. Here is an attempt.

```
function p(msg) { console.log(msg) }

let wav1 = [0.1,0.2,0.3]
let wav = new Float32Array(wav1)
p(`Len array to encrypt=${wav.length}`)
let omsg = JSON.stringify({onset: { id: 'abc', cntr: 1234}, wav: atob(wav) })
p(omsg)
```

The `atob`  gives:

```
 Uncaught InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': 
 The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded."
```

What intermediate step is needed to allow proper encoding of the floats to base64 ?  Note that I have also tried `TweetNacl-util` instead of `atob` this way:

```
 nacl.util.encodeBase64(wav)
```

This results in the same error.

**Update**  Using `JSON.stringify` directly converts each float element into its ascii equivalent - which bloats the datasize . For the above that is:

> &quot;0.10000000149011612,&quot;1&quot;:0.20000000298023224,&quot;2&quot;:0.30000001192092896

We are transferring large arrays so this is a suboptimal solution.

**Update** The crucial element of the solution in the accepted answer is using `Float32Array(floats).buffer` .  I was unaware of the `buffer` attribute.

Comment: It should be [`btoa`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa) if you're encoding to base64... But `btoa` works on strings, not `Float32Array`s. Why not just let `JSON.stringify` do the serialization?

Comment: Does `JSON.stringify` retain the float arrays as 4 bytes per element? I see it coming out as the ascii version of each element - which is like 16 bytes per element (see update to question)

Comment: Use whatever you saw for Uint8Array on an Uint8Array view of your Float32Array's buffer. The Typed Array is just a view, you can create many of these on the same buffer without any new data assigned. But how come you can't transfer the binary data directly? (Send the buffer directly)

Comment: @Kaiido  The data will be encrypted next: can not do that on floats afaik. In any case the `Tweet-Nacl` library does not support it.

Comment: The data is binary data, that you have a Float32Array view over that data doesn't change that. Once again TypedArrays are only views. If some code needs to read the data as Uint8Array, then give them a Uint8Array view of your underlying buffer. There is no float or whatever only data.

Comment: @Kaiido  the `.buffer` on the `TypedArray` is what I was missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your current code is that `nacl.util.encodeBase64()` takes in either a string, `Array`, or `Uint8Array`. Since your input isn't an `Array` or `Uint8Array`, it assumes you want to pass it in as a string.

The solution, of course, is to encode it into a `Uint8Array` first, then encode the `Uint8Array` into base64. When you decode, first decode the base64 into a `Uint8Array`, then convert the `Uint8Array` back into your `Float32Array`. This can be done using JavaScript `ArrayBuffer`.

```js
const floatSize = 4;

function floatArrayToBytes(floats) {
    var output = floats.buffer; // Get the ArrayBuffer from the float array
    return new Uint8Array(output); // Convert the ArrayBuffer to Uint8s.
}

function bytesToFloatArray(bytes) {
    var output = bytes.buffer; // Get the ArrayBuffer from the Uint8Array.
    return new Float32Array(output); // Convert the ArrayBuffer to floats.
}

var encoded = nacl.util.encodeBase64(floatArrayToBytes(wav)) // Encode
var decoded = bytesToFloatArray(nacl.util.decodeBase64(encoded)) // Decode
```

If you don't like functions, here's some one-liners!

```js
var encoded = nacl.util.encodeBase64(new Uint8Array(wav.buffer)) // Encode
var decoded = new Float32Array(nacl.util.decodeBase64(encoded).buffer) // Decode
```

Comment: The key to what you wrote - and which is what I needed is

```floats.buffer```

I am awarding for that piece. Thanks!