# Base64-decoded Float32Array is longer than the encoded one. Why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, base64

I've been trying a few different solutions to Base64 encode and decode a javascript `Float32Array` so I can send it to my Web API in a JSON doc.   But every time I decode the string back to an array of float, I get a longer one than I started with.  I've tried the following approaches

- this [tweet-nacl-util](https://github.com/StableLib/stablelib/blob/a7bac13/packages/base64/base64.ts#L276) approach first mentioned [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63713889/convert-float32array-to-base64-in-javascript)
- the ArrayBuffer approach [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267899/arraybuffer-to-base64-encoded-string):
- even [this approach](https://github.com/hughsk/tab64) I stumbled across

They all "work" in that they encode my `Float32Array` which has a length of 76800 to a BASE64 string.  But whenever I decode that string, I get a longer array.   Even when I use their own "decode" functions.

For example here is me testing the first approach, but I see this with all of them. ('pcdRef.current' is my `Float32Array`).  This code...

```
var base64String = encode(new Uint8Array(pcdRef.current.buffer));            
var prev = decode(base64String)
var prevArray = new Float32Array(prev.buffer);

console.log("original length = " + pcdRef.current.length + ", rehydrated length = " + prevArray.length);
```

...gives me this console output

```
original length = 76800, rehydrated length = 77284
```

The same is true of the data that my actual Web API receives.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double-check the properties of the Float32Array's underlying buffer.  A TypedArray (such as Float32Array) may be created as a [view of an underlying buffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray#behavior_when_viewing_a_resizable_buffer), **at an [arbitrary offset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/byteOffset) and with [an arbitrary length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/byteLength)**. This means that accessing an array's buffer *without* also processing `byteOffset` and `byteLength` may fail.

Demonstration:

```js
const buffer = new ArrayBuffer(16);
const array = new Float32Array(buffer, 4, 3);

console.log(array.buffer === buffer); // true
console.log(array.buffer.byteLength); // 16
console.log(array.length * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT); // 12

// This incorrectly gets the full buffer:
console.log(new Uint8Array(array.buffer).length); // 16
// This gets the portion of the buffer corresponding to the Float32Array.
// The third parameter is array length, which for Uint8 is byte length.
console.log(new Uint8Array(array.buffer, array.byteOffset, array.byteLength).length); // 12
```

Try using the following code instead.

```
const base64String = encode(new Uint8Array(
  pcdRef.current.buffer,
  pcdRef.current.byteOffset,
  pcdRef.current.byteLength
));
```

Comment: That was it exactly!  Thank you.  I would probably have stumbled around for days on that!